# How to tell if an Angular2 module is ok to import into shared module

Tags: angular

Is there a litmus test for determining if a module is a provider or exports other modules that are providers; for determining if a module is a candidate for being listed in the "shared" module?

From angular.io:

"The SharedModule should not have providers for reasons explained previously. Nor should any of its imported or re-exported modules have providers. If you deviate from this guideline, know what you're doing and why."

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-module-recommendations

However if I go to use a module, let's say the ReactiveFormsModule or the RoutingModule, how do I determine if that passes the test described above?  If I am only to use modules in the SharedModule that do not have providers or imported modules that re-export providers, then surely there must be some way to tell if a module meets this requirement.  What is it?

Comment: @Aravind Opinion based  = "is angular better than react ?". This question is "what's a good way to structure my app considering this ?", although it has some opinions in it, it has its feet grounded on logic. Stackoverflow is becoming less and less noob friendly by the days. /rant  (this is not an attack to your comment, it's just the possibility of this question being locked that annoys me)

Comment: ok.  I chopped the question to it's essence...

Comment: I think your question is about providers in a shared module - not components. May help to revise your title?

Comment: Thanks. Might be. I'm struggling a bit. this page:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module

gives me the impression that I can or should put modules like FormsModule into shared to reduce code duplication.  then import sharedModule where you need FormsModule.  So that begs the question what other modules can or should be in shared and how do I determine their fitness for that.  I understand the info about shared services.

Answer (score 2):

Services are generally intended to be Singletons with application-wide scope.

When a module is imported, the Services provided by the imported module are added to the host module's injector.  By having services within a shared module, there is a real danger of multiple modules importing the shared module and creating multiple copies of the service, each with module scope.  Make sure that if you add a service to a SharedModule, that this is what you intended.

According to best practices, you should have a set of Core modules per application. These Core modules are not shared (it should only be imported by the AppModule) so it would be safe to add Services to the Core modules without breaking the Singleton intent.

The litmus test:

> If you want Singleton Services that are shared application-wide, then
>   don't put them in a **SharedModule** because **SharedModules** could be
>   imported from multiple modules within the ***same*** application.  Instead
>   put them in **CoreModules**, which should only be imported by the
>   AppModule.

Remember the following conventions and guidelines:

1. There is only one AppModule per Application
2. AppModules can import other modules
3. Core modules should only be imported by the AppModule
4. Shared modules can be imported by any module (not just the AppModule)

Answer (score 1):

Common ways of doing things are as in the below image.

[image]

Usually providers are always listed in the `providers[]` of the respective module if their scope is limited to that particular module, else move it to the Root module AppModule.

Comment: Thanks. The documentation of FormsModule has a provider listed, "RadioControlRegistry." And ReactiveFormsModule has two providers listed.  "FormBuilder, RadioControlRegistry."  So then why is it ok to put them in the shared module?  Again I'm looking for a litmus test, if there is one.  As I'm building my application I don't want to post to stack overflow every time I need to use a new module.  It seems to me there should be some scientific way to determine and on the most common example given, the FormsModule, it clearly breaks the rule given.

Comment: @Boice A few years late on this one xp. But wo